# Generate inline Bokeh scatterplots in Jupyter using a for loop

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, bokeh

I am trying to plot three Bokeh scatterplots inline in a Jupyter notebook. I’ve been able to do this previously, but after updating Bokeh, I can't get it to work. Is there something I need to do differently now?

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, output_notebook, show
output_notebook()


x = dfList[0][1]['ValueA']

for i in range(0,3):

    #Define figure
    p = figure(plot_width=900, plot_height=600,     
          tools="pan,wheel_zoom,lasso_select,box_zoom,reset,save,undo")

    #Add four datasets to figure
    for t in range(4):
        y = dfList[t][1]['ValueB']
        plot_data = p.circle(x,y)

    #Display figure in notebook
    show(p)
```

With the code above, only the first plot displays. I have tried

```
from bokeh.plotting import reset_output
```

and adding `reset_output()` after `show(p)` on each iteration, which does generate the three plots, but they are each output in a separate browser tab, which is not what I want.

If I also add `output_notebook()` each iteration, rather than just in the first cell of my notebook, then I still only get the first plot, with the “Loading BokehJS…” message displayed below for the other two iterations.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that worked previously I'd say it was unintentional undefined behavior. The `show` function has always had in mind that it was for *replacing* the output in the next output cells, so running it multiple times in one cell was never a usage pattern that was considered. In any event, adding support for support JupyterLab has necessitated various changes to notebook display machinery, and that's probably the immediate reason you are seeing a difference. However, I would say that the current behavior is correct, and what should be expected going forward.

The right way to do something like this is to collect the plots in a layout of some kind, and then show the layout:

```
from bokeh.layouts import column
layout = column()

for x in foo:

    p = figure()
    layout.children.append(p)

show(layout)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Makes much more sense to specify a layout.